# Switching to Ubuntu. What version?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I'm going to switch to Ubuntu 12.10 from Windows 7, but I'm considering waiting for 13.04 instead.

What would you suggest?

Comment: I'm a fan of LTS so 12.04 LTS is my suggestion and is not necessary to waiting for , install it now. If you want the latest version (13.04) I would suggest to wait and make a fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install 12.10 now and upgrade then to 13.04.
Or just reinstall if 13.04 when it is released, if you like to do some tryouts.

If you don't like to upgrade every 6 Months you can use the Version 12.04 LTS (Long Term Support). Ubuntu provides system updates für 5 years for LTS-Versions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question but simply looking for suggestions, so it possibly will be closed, however I would suggest you grab 12.10 and upgrade when 13.04 comes out, you'll get a notification and it wont effect any of your personal files or configuration.